# Java getElmentsByTagName with Wildcard

Tags: java, xml, dom, getelementsbytagname

I try to compare two XML files. But not all of the XML elments just the one that starts with for example `"ns:"`. Is that possible?

I tried:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("ns:" + * );
```

Thanks, 
LB

Answer (score 0):

You can't match on the prefix but on the namespace uri:

Say you have a document

```
<doc xmlns:ns="http://example.org">
    <ns:a/>
    <ns:b/>
    <c/>
</doc>
```

you can select all elements with namespace uri `http://example.org` (i.e. `a` and `b`) with

```
document.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://example.org", "*")
```